# How to get extension of a file in shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to get file extension for a file in shell script. But without any luck.

The command I am using is

```
file_ext=${filename##*.}
```

and

```
file_ext = $filename |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'
```

But both of the commands failed to put value in variable file_ext. But when i try

```
echo $filename |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'
```

It gives me the desired result. I am new to shell script. Please describe the situation what is happening. And also how should I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: For further references, http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ is a very good place!

Comment: I am wondering why the first style works. Could you please explain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Spaces hurt.

Anyway you should do:

```
file_ext=$(echo $filename | awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}')
```

[Edit] Better suggestion by Martin:

```
file_ext=$(printf '%s' "$filename" | awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}')
```

That will store in `$file_ext` the output of the command.

Comment: Yes. The idea was to the command in $(). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Besser use `printf '%s' "$filename"` instead of `echo $filename`. See the difference with `touch -- -e '-e foo.txt\n\cbar.exe'; echo 'echoing all files:'; for f in *; do echo $f; done; echo 'printing all files:'; for f in *; do printf '%s\n' "$f"; done`

Comment: The awk part can be simplified to `awk -F . 'NF > 1 {print $NF}'`.

Answer (score 25):

to get file extension, just use the shell

```
$ filename="myfile.ext"
$ echo ${filename##*.}
ext
$ file_ext=${filename##*.} #put to variable
$ echo ${file_ext}
ext
```

Comment: Yeah but why does this work? What is this `##*.` voodoo?

Comment: lol @Okonomiyaki3000, bash scripting is mostly voodoo to me XD. This works because `{var##somepattern}` is a parameter. `##somepattern` essentially removes the pattern from the var, so it's removing everything up to the dot. The one gotcha with this is that if the pattern is not found, the whole string is returned (which may or may not be desirable, in my case, I wanted to return an empty string when no extension exists). Here's a good article on parameter substitution:  https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about this useful feature!

Comment: Just checked this also works when the filename contains multiple dots. E.g. `filename="myfile.log.gz"` will return `gz`, as expected.

Comment: More voodoo here - https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html (Section 2.6.2 - Parameter Expansion).

Comment: If its `tar.tar.gz` can we get `tar.gz` instead of `gz`?

Answer (score 3):

You have to be careful when declaring variables.

```
variable1="string"    # assign a string value
variable3=`command`   # assign output from command
variable2=$(command)  # assign output from command
```

Notice that you **cannot** put a space after the variable, because then it gets interpreted as a normal command.

Comment: Thanks well interpreted. :) . I got your point will never do this mistake.